# docker(-compose): access wikijs container only through nginx-proxy-manager; 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-502

I'm running a server that I want to setup to provide several webservices. One service is WikiJS.

I want the service to only be accessible through nginx-proxy-manager via a subdomain, but not directly accessing the IP (and port) of the server.

My try was:

```
version: "3"




services:
  nginxproxymanager:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '8181:81' # Admin Web Port
      # Add any other Stream port you want to expose
      # - '21:21' # FTP

    # Uncomment the next line if you uncomment anything in the section
    # environment:
      # Uncomment this if you want to change the location of
      # the SQLite DB file within the container
      # DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/data/database.sqlite"

      # Uncomment this if IPv6 is not enabled on your host
      # DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'

    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - reverseproxy-nw

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ###DBPW
      POSTGRES_USER: wikijs
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - reverseproxy-nw

  wiki:
    image: requarks/wiki:2
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: wikijs
      DB_PASS: ###DBPW
      DB_NAME: wiki
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    networks:
      - reverseproxy-nw

volumes:
  db-data:


networks:
  reverseproxy-nw:
    external: true
```

In nginx-proxy-manager I then tried to use "wikijs" as the forwarding host.
[image]

The service is accessible if I try: http://publicip:3001, however not via the assigned subdomain in nginx-proxy-manager. I only get a 502 which usually means, that nginx-proxy-manager cannot access the given service.

What do I have to change to make the service available unter the domain but not from http://publicip:3001 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found out what my conceptual problem was:
I needed to create a network bridge for the two containers. Basically it was as basic as specifying the driver of the network:

```
networks:
  reverseproxy-nw:
    driver: bridge
```

Like this the wikijs-container is only available through nginx as I want it to be.